# How do offline updates work?

Tags: updates, kubuntu, 22.04, reboot, offline

[image]

[image]

I'm in Kubuntu 22.04 and I have used this relative new (at least to me) feature of "offline updates" which basically forces you to restart in order to apply the update the way Fedora and infamously MSWindows do.

I have always hated the MSWindows aggressive behavior on this but had sympathy for Fedora's way, oriented towards more stability, so I have welcomed this in K/ubuntu.

What I want to know is related to a few interconnected points:

- After enabling this I am forced to restart very often. I'm on a laptop and restarting twice a week or more is ridiculous these days. For example this required restart:

[image]

- On the other hand, seeing my wifi stop during an update because wifi drivers etc are reinstalled always seemed ugly. -- Shouldn't restarts be reserved for delicate cases?
- What are the delicate cases (beside kernel)? - Unattended or automatic upgrades are disabled on my system, I only upgrade if I want, but I tend to think I should update more often than I'd like to restart.
- Is there a need to reboot for snap (also flatpak) updates?
- Thinking about it, I would guess that all updates that involve parts of the running system excepting maybe icons and such should require restart. How come for years I have used Linux and Ubuntu *without* this feature?
- Why is this feature optional?
- I'm strongly inclined to disable offline updates OR to update less often (once two weeks?) - What "should" I do?
- *What happens if I don't restart after an update when I'm prompted to?* (*if i simply quit the Discover notifier for example or let it run) - Will new updates be presented to me or will I have to restart for new updates?

Comment: You can fully disable automatic updates and unattended upgrades, and only update the computer when at a time that works for you.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi - You mean *enable* offline updates but update only when I'm ready to restart?

Comment: @Rinzwind - `4: no`. That means that for snap, just like for icons updates, we are not prompted to reboot, but that, when we are prompted, not doing it involves a risk. I think my points are related and that opinion-orriented ones can be answered based on the non-opinion ones. But: 6 is `Why is this feature optional?`. That is not asking for opinion (it's about the necessity of reboot).

Comment: @Rinzwind - I have updated the last point(s)

Comment: @cipricus "Is there a need to reboot for snap (also flatpak) updates?" there is NO need to reboot; I did not say this feature does not prompt for a reboot ;-) "Why is this feature optional?" but all you can get from us would be "because it is". The ONLY person that can answer this with a reasoning is the creator.  Hmm I don't like the word "offline" with this feature. That assumes with no internet. Not during a reboot. Man how I hate this feature in Windows D: D: I am biased against this option in kUbuntu cuz of that :-X

Comment: @Rinzwind - Indeed, isn't there anything "offline"=off-internet happening there? Maybe its that that download is before reboot, and installation is before online connection. Anyway what counts here is that installation is before system boot, offline or not, so the term is misleading. Correct?

Comment: Yes I agree. "offline installation" I would assume something like the ability to transport a prepared download to a machine that has no internet to then perform an update/upgrade. This feature is more "Update your system before turning the machine off" kind of thing. I wonder what would happen if the machine is turned off during this action :D